# bash prompt user to edit string and enter

Tags: linux, bash

I want to present the user with a string to edit and enter.
For example:

```
$edpath filen*
 Edit> /home/user1/bla/bla/foo/bar/bar/dir1/dir2/filename.xyz
```

And after the user edits the string and hits enter:

```
You entered: /home/user2/foobar/dir1/dir2/filename.xyz
$
```

What bash command does this, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bash `4.1+` (or so, I'm not sure of the exact version).

```
$ read -re -p 'Edit> ' -i '/home/user1/bla/bla/foo/bar/bar/dir1/dir2/filename.xyz' filename
$ echo "You entered: $filename"
```